# How to ignore swagger resource property for specific http verb(GET,POST,PUT)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0, springfox

We are implemented spring fox swagger 2 of version 2.6.1, i wanted to display a specific property of a resource for HTTP GET METHOD and not for POST METHOD, i haven't find any approach using swagger 2. Please help thanks.

For example:

```
Class Employee{

Integer id;
String name;

}
```

Request URI: GET /api/employee/{id}
i should see the swagger request document as

```
{
  id:"",
  name:""
}
```

Request URI: POST /api/employee
i should see the swagger request sample as

```
{
    name:""
}
```

Comment: This is currently not possible in springfox 2.6.1

Comment: Thank you Dilip for the response , do we have any another approach to achieve this ?

Comment: By not possible I mean it's a feature request that hasn't been implemented. The way to get around it is to use separate models for each of the operations.

Comment: any updates to this?

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to version 2.8.0 and it is possible with @ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true). This causes the property to be #Returned by GET, not used in POST / PUT / PATCH

Comment: This readOnly flag is deprecated, and specifying accessMode=AccessMode.READ_ONLY doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This was the valid response in older swagger.

```
@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
```

In Swagger V3 you need to use AccesMode. Example:

```
@Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
private long id;
```

This will make id visible for all GET requests.