# OpenApi hide a model property in the request

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I know we can use this `@ApiModelProperty` annotation from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57757755/2462531) to hide an `id` from the request when we use `Swagger-Ui`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I am using this spring doc OpenApi dependency

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
       <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.32</version>
 </dependency>
```

I am not getting this annotation `@ApiModelProperty` when I used `springdoc-openapi-ui`. What could be the annotation for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace swagger 2 annotations with swagger 3 annotations (it is already included with springdoc-openapi-ui dependency). Package for swagger 3 annotations is io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.

It's all explained here:

- https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html