# hide or ignore json property in yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

i am using open api generator for request and response objects generation. I  want to hide/ignore the json field from yaml. So i have tried by using this config in yaml-> `x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore" or import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden`. Below is the generated code

```
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String name;
```

and for Hidden

```
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    @Hidden
    private String name;
```

But i can see name in response. Please suggest how to ignore or hide the name field from response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263086/how-to-hide-a-request-field-in-swagger-api

Comment: @cool  how to set APIModelProperty(hidden = true) for that field in yaml?

Comment: it looks like I misunderstood your question. When you say you want to hide that field from response do you mean when the value is not provided don't send it? If so you should set this annotation on the field @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: @cool  tried like this x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)" but getting compilation error saying Include does not exist. Library also there.

Comment: try this x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)"

Answer (score 0):

Create a Views class and create two views – Public and Private:

```
    public class Views {
        public static class Public {}
    
        public static class Private {}
    }
```

after that annoted name field with @JsonView like below.

```
    @JsonView(Views.Private.class)
    private String name;
```

I think it's work fine for you.

Comment: I'm generating java class from yaml. Can you suggest how to set value for that field in yaml

Comment: can you please share your yaml file here??

Comment: ```ResponseDTO:
  type: object
  properties:  
     emp:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type : string
        name:
          type: string
          x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore" ```